# Determining the address that is causing double page fault

Tags: linux, fault, page-fault

A hardware is performing memory operation and resulting in a page-fault. How can I determine the virtual address that is causing following double fault error message so that I can pin the address?

```
[   52.330981] PANIC: double fault, error_code: 0x0
[   52.331972] Kernel panic - not syncing: Machine halted.
[   52.332916] CPU: 0 PID: 1432 Comm: stress Tainted: G           OE    4.15.0-23-generic #25~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[   52.334584] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.11.1-0-g0551a4be2c-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
[   52.336673] Call Trace:
[   52.337151]  <#DF>
[   52.337549]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
[   52.338152]  panic+0xe4/0x244
[   52.338690]  df_debug+0x2d/0x30
[   52.339450]  do_double_fault+0x9a/0x130
[   52.340187]  double_fault+0x1e/0x30
[   52.340836] RIP: 0010:error_entry+0x1e/0x100
[   52.341674] RSP: 0000:fffffe0000002000 EFLAGS: 00010046
[   52.342605] RAX: 0000000090c009e7 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: ffffffff90c009e7
[   52.343896] RDX: 0000000004ba1000 RSI: ffffffff90c015ff RDI: fffffe0000002078
[   52.345153] RBP: fffffe0000002079 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[   52.346407] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
[   52.347739] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[   52.349054]  ? native_iret+0x7/0x7
[   52.349729]  ? async_page_fault+0xf/0x50
[   52.350463]  </#DF>
[   52.350908]  <ENTRY_TRAMPOLINE>
[   52.351503] RIP: 0010:do_async_page_fault+0x0/0x80
[   52.352443] RSP: 0000:fffffe0000002120 EFLAGS: 00010012
[   52.353416] RAX: 0000000090c009e7 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: ffffffff90c009e7
[   52.354770] RDX: 0000000004ba1000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: fffffe0000002128
[   52.356160] RBP: fffffe0000002129 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[   52.357500] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
[   52.358814] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[   52.360157]  ? native_iret+0x7/0x7
[   52.360849]  ? kvm_async_pf_task_wait+0x220/0x220
[   52.361717]  ? async_page_fault+0x25/0x50
[   52.362521]  ? native_iret+0x7/0x7
[   52.363136] RIP: 0010:async_page_fault+0x0/0x50
[   52.364052] RSP: 0000:fffffe00000021d0 EFLAGS: 00010006
[   52.365021] RAX: 00007f780fef3010 RBX: 00007f780b352010 RCX: 00007f780b352010
[   52.366391] RDX: 0000000004ba1000 RSI: 0000000008001000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   52.367729] RBP: 0000000008000000 R08: ffffffffffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
[   52.369046] R10: 0000000000000022 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000001000
[   52.370437] R13: 00007f7813351010 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: fffffffffffff000
[   52.372447]  ? async_page_fault+0x25/0x50
[   52.373650]  </ENTRY_TRAMPOLINE>
[   52.374788] Kernel Offset: 0xf200000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[   52.376319] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Machine halted.
```